# Mock a function which is called when a module is imported

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest, mox

I want to test a module `A` which uses decorators with arguments. The arguments get evaluated when the module `A` is loaded. For some of the decorator args, I set the value by calling a function `foo` in module `B`.

```
# A.py
import B

@deco(arg1=B.foo())
def bar():
  ...
```

When I want to test `A`, I want to mock `B.foo` so that the decorator argument is set for my test cases. I think that `B.foo` must be mocked before `A` loads `B`.

In the unit test, as a caller of `A`, how do I mock `B.foo` to ensure the mocked version is used when evaluating the decorator arguments in `A`?

Comment: Please provide relevant code segments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to ensure that the mock is really used, you have to reload module `A` after patching `foo`, as `bar` already had been evaluated with the original `foo`. You could wrap that in a fixture like this (untested):

```
import importlib
import pytest
from unittest import mock
import A

@pytest.fixture
def mocked_foo():
    with mock.patch('B.foo') as mocked:
        importlib.reload(A)
        yield mocked

def test_bar(mocked_foo):
    ...
```