# Python - Test if a function is called when importing a script in a unittest

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, pytest

I have a script in which I start with running a function. i.e.

```
foo.py

from bar import some_func
some_func()

# rest of code
```

I want to make sure that this function will always be run first, hence I want to create a unittest which imports `foo.py` and assert whether its called.

I tried the following:

```
test_import.py

@mock.patch("foo.some_func")
def test_func_called_on_import(some_func_mock):
    import foo
    some_func_mock.assert_called_once()
```

But that results in an error stating it was called 0 times. Does anyone have experience in such a testcase?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: These might help:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/62032268/2532408 https://stackoverflow.com/q/62397873/2532408

Comment: Thanks for sharing, unfortunately the solutions don't work for what i'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Can you explain?  or explain why that doesn't answer what you're looking for?